# Magento2 - Change customer group programatically conditionally

Tags: magento2, php

I need to dynamically change logged in customer group ID to get products prices from another group. I tried :

```
$this->session->setCustomerGroupId(NEWGROUPID);
```

It's working great for product pages and categories pages but it does not work on checkout cart and onepage.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code :**

```
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
         CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    //ends here
    public function execute(){      
        $id = 3; // Customer id
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($id);
        $group_id = 4; // New group id
        $customer->setGroupId($group_id);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to really change my customer group I want this modification to be virtual.